# Auto Scale y axis in real time graph

Tags: c

I am trying plot a real time graph with x axis raging from 0 to -40 and y axis ranging rom 0 to 200000000. How Can i auto scale this graph in C?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. If what you are trying to archive is to fit the samples into an area of WxH pixels you can just scale them:

```
float d = max_y - min_y;
float s = (sample - min_y) / d;
int y = s * height;
```